# Typescript showing can not set property of undefined, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface IGroup{
    groupNumber:number;
    groupMembers:Array<ISeatPlanGroup>;
    totalStudentNumber:number;
  }
```

When, I try to assign a value in the groupNumber, then, compiler says , can not set property of undefined.

```
              var group: IGroup;
              group.groupNumber = groupArr[i].groupNo;
              group.groupMembers=[];
              group.groupMembers.push(groupArr[i]);
              group.totalStudentNumber = 0;
              group.totalStudentNumber+=groupArr[i].studentNumber;
```

I also tried to initialize

```
group.groupNumber = 0;
```

Still, there is error. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

By giving your type you don't initialize your object  to initialize your object

```
var group: any= {}
```

Comment: Probably not with a raw object, though.

Comment: Correct, it should be `any` in this case

Answer (score 1):

`var group: IGroup;` doesn't create any object, it just says what type of reference `group` can hold. `group` starts out with the value `undefined`.

You have to assign an object to `group` that implements `IGroup`. Say for instance you have a `Group` class that implements `IGroup`. Then you'd do this:

```
var group: IGroup = new Group();
```

Of course, your actual class name may not be `Group`, and the actual class's constructor may require arguments, but fundamentally the issue is that you haven't assigned an object to `group`.